# How to include a page with dynamic response using ajax and xmlhttp.open

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a page linked to the database with GET, something like this: 
http://example.com/?data=1

Every time I change the get value the info changes. 
I would like to include(?) this page on another (with menus etc), so when I click on a link or something change just the info of the include:

```
<div class="div1"> Show data 1 </div>
<div class="div2"> Show data 2 </div>
<div class="data"> (Show data from http://example.com/?data=1) </div>
```

I have read that I would need to use ajax xmlhttp.open, but I just can't figure out how to include the page with dynamic response in the db.

So if you have a simple tutorial or something, or some ideas would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can put a [jQuery load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) call inside the menu click handler:

```
$('.data').load('http://example.com/?data=1');
```